# Is it correct to say "Data are transferred"

Tags: construction

I am a bit confused. When multiple data (plural) transfer takes place, which would be the correct expression:
a. "data are transferred"
b. "data is transferred"

Or both expressions are correct?

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 2):

From Websters dictionary

Data is plural in form but is used with both plural and singular verbs.

Is this data accurate?

Are these data reliable?

When used with plural verbs, data is thought of as the plural form of the noun datum. It is usually used with plural verbs only in formal or technical writing.

Many of these data are incorrect.

So both are possible.